# What is the meaning of "is must to "

Tags: meaning

I have read this sentence but I can not understand it. Under which circumstances is this type of sentence is? Also, please tell me which grammar rule has been applied.

> they will open our salary account so it is must to bring the originals

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: This looks to me like a sentence written by somebody who does not know English very well.

Comment: I also observe that a _salary account_ is not a phrase I have ever heard before: is it perhaps common in Indian English?

Comment: "Salary account" seems OK to me (in the US).  But of course "is this type of sentence is" also lacks grammaticalitynesses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a complete sentence, the grammar is wrong.

Perhaps it should be:

> They will open our salary account, so it is a must to bring the originals.

(Notice I have added "a" before "must".)  Here, [must](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/must#Noun) is a noun that means "a thing that is mandatory / required".

Comment: I have read "it is must that..." to mean "it is required to... but it was in very old English, in this case it is bad grammar.

Comment: I think that "a must" is commonly located right at the end of the sentence: "Daily exercise is a must".

Comment: I can't imagine any context in which I would find Pitarou's amended text natural. It is grammatical, but nobody would say it, because "a must" is much more informal than the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Why are you assuming that it was written by a native speaker?

Answer (score 5):

I doubt whether any native speaker of English would say that - it definitely sounds wrong to my (native) ears.  Perhaps you could say

> They will open our salary account, so it is necessary to bring the originals.

instead.

Comment: +1 because I feel that when something is "a must," it is really just very strongly recommended.  "If you go to Paris, seeing the Eiffel Tower is a must."  "When you're on the lake fishing all day, sun block is a must."   In the questioner's scenario, it's not "a must," it's "a requirement."